# SQL Script Transaction Log to Table Report

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I am trying to write a script that I can run to create a report that will look through a table (customer transaction log) and will count the number of times each customer uses each transaction type for each location. For report purposes I NEED only single line for each customer.

eg Transaction Table

```
CustomerID  TransactionType TransactionLocation Timestamp

90214X      ESL             WBEE                20140301

90214X      LOTE            WBEE                20140301

90214X      ESL             WBEE                20140302

90214X      LOTE            VALE                20140303

90214X      ESL             WBEE                20140302

90214X      ESL             VALE                20140302

90633X      LOTE            WBEE                20140301

90633X      ESL             VALE                20140302

90678X      ESL             WBEE                20140303
```

report needs to be

```
CustomerID  WBEEESL  WBEELOTE VALEESL VALELOTE

90214X      3        1        1       1

90633X      0        1        1       0

90678X      1        0        0       0
```

I will be require to run the script on a regular basis and would like to create the script so I can automate the process.

(sorry table wouldnt layout nicely here)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomerID
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionType     = 'ESL' 
               AND TransactionLocation = 'WBEE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS WBEEESL
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionType     = 'LOTE' 
               AND TransactionLocation = 'WBEE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS WBELOTE
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionType     = 'ESL' 
               AND TransactionLocation = 'VALE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS VALEESL
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN TransactionType     = 'LOTE' 
               AND TransactionLocation = 'VALE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS VALELOTE
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks this work perfected, can you do similar if you need to add values for these conditions instead of counting.